# JWPlayer 7 sdk / code examples

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am developing JWPlayer plugins in order to use with our own video distributions. In JWPlayer's [GitHub page](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdks) there are sdks for JWPlayer 6 but not 7. For plugins, the README says:

> JW6 plugins are supported in JW Player 7 for legacy purposes.

I am wondering if there are sdks for JW7? Because it seems the JW6 plugins could be deprecated in the next version. Or, if sdks are not available yet, any place I can find JW7 custom plugin and provider examples?

p.s. yes I have checked out the source code of [JW7 at GitHub](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer). I can compile the the source code with `grunt` and even wrote a provider based on the `html5` provider. However I can't figure out if it's possible at all NOT to touch JW7's source code in order to use a custom provider or plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are SDKs available for Android and iOS for JW Player and they are free. Github links and documentation here: https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/
https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/docs/developer-guide/intro/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks for the reply HeidiWF. Do you know where I can find examples of custom JW7 providers and plugins (not JW6 ones because I know they're in GitHub)? Thank you.